# ssh command cannot return the result executed on remote machine

Tags: shell, jenkins, ssh

when I use ssh to execute remote file in shell script, so that I could get the result executed on remote machine, however, I met a problem which the user defined variables could not be recognized.

1. I created a shell script run.sh like this

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ssh jenkins@10.122.214.55 << EOF
   ./test.sh && ret=1 || ret=0 
   echo "before" 
   echo ${ret}
   echo "after"
   echo ${HOME}
   exit ${ret}
   EOF
   ```
2. the content of test.sh which is called by run.sh :

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "lala"
   exit 1
   ```
3. when I call ./run.sh
   it print like this

   ```
   lala
   before

   after
   /home/jenkins
   ```

Why did not it echo `${ret}`? After ./run.sh is called, echo $? is 0 which is unexpected, I thought it should echo 1 here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because the variables in the heredoc are being expanded by the local script before being sent to the standard input of ssh.

In other words, your heredoc behaves similarly to

```
#!/bin/bash
string="echo \"before\"
echo ${ret}
echo \"after\"
echo ${HOME}
exit ${ret}
./test.sh && ret=1 || ret=0"
echo "$string" | ssh jenkins@10.122.214.55
```

which makes it more obvious that the string has the variables interpolated.

There are a couple ways around this: either you can escape the `$` symbols (e.g. `echo \${ret}`) so that the intended string is passed through, or you can use a verbatim heredoc

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh jenkins@10.122.214.55 <<'EOF'
./test.sh && ret=1 || ret=0
echo "before"
echo ${ret}
echo "after"
echo ${HOME}
exit ${ret}
EOF
```

By single-quoting the delimiter, we ensure that no expansion takes place inside the heredoc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's very helpful